# Resolving Google Search Console Error: Video Too Tall for Embedded YouTube URLs

Tags: php

I'm facing a Google Search Console error stating "Video Too Tall" for embedded YouTube URLs on my WordPress site. I found a PHP snippet that claims to fix this by setting a specific height for embedded videos:

```
function wpb_auto_embed_size() {
    return array(
        'width'  => 640,
        'height' => 900,
    );
}
add_filter('embed_defaults', 'wpb_auto_embed_size');
```

Will this snippet automatically resolve the "Video Too Tall" error for all existing embedded YouTube URLs?

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9495631#indexing_status